# Assessing parameter bias in simulation

Tags: simulation

```
set.seed(123456)          
reps <- 500      # no. of repetitions
par.est <- matrix(NA, nrow= reps, ncol=2)   # empty matrix to store the estimates

b0 <- .2     # true value for the intercept
b1 <- .5     # true value for the slope
n <- 1000    # sample size
X <- runif(n, -1, 1) # create a sample of n obs on the independent variable x

for (i in 1:reps){                  # start of the loop
    Y <- b0 +b1*X + rnorm(n,0,1)     # the true DGP, with N(0,1) error
   model <-lm(Y~X)                  # estimate the OLS model
   par.est[i,1] <- model$coef[1]    # put the estimate for the intercept in the 1st column
   par.est[i, 2] <- model$coef[2]   # put the estimates for the coefficient of X in the 2nd column
```

}

Can someone show me how to assess the bias in the estimates of the intercept and the slope?

Comment: [Bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator) is a property of estimators, not estimates.  OLS estimators are BLUE (Best Linear **Unbiased** Estimators) when the residuals and the independent variables are uncorrelated and have constant variance, and since you generated iid normal residuals that requirement is met.  QED the bias is zero. If you didn't actually mean bias, please clarify your question.

Comment: I don't know how best to call it, but I wanted to see how the value of the parameters are well recovered in this kind of simulation. The true values of intercept and slope are .2 and .5, respectively. So based on the simulated values of the intercept and slope, I wanted to know the R code how to measure bias in the estimated intercept and slope.

Comment: Again, the OLS estimators are unbiased. The bias is zero. When the estimates are not exactly equal to [0.2, 0.5] it's because of variance in the estimators, not bias.

Comment: I wonder whether this might be a better question for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), the SE site for statistics questions.  Is it that you're not sure you understand the concepts or mathematical methods needed to answer your question?  Or is that you understand the mathematical methods, but aren't sure how to translate them into code?  If it's the first question, it's more appropriate for Cross Validated.  If it's the second question, then it sounds as if you haven't yet given enough detail about what's puzzling you.  (pjs's comments would be appropriate for C.V., too.)

Comment: I do understand the response of pjs and the statistical concepts behind it. I asked only to see if someone can help me translate them into R codes. More specifically, I was interested in assessing the performance of a statistical estimation method such as OLS in terms of bias, efficiency, and accuracy after having generated/simulated data. Again, I was only looking for help on how to translate them into R codes.